# Mongoose removes too many from ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I may be misunderstanding something, but on the client I have a request sent to the server.  Something like:

```
$.post("/resources/remove", {"id": 52024e25b26d39f931000003})
```

On the server I have

```
Resource.remove({_id: request.body.id})
```

The "ID" is correct and using `Resource.find` with the same arguments returns the record I want to remove.  However, when this is run it removes *all* `Resource` records.  The return value of `exec(function (err, returnValue)` is the number of `Resource` records that were there, so it is definitely removing all of them.  Using `Remove.(request.body.id)` does the same thing.

Do I need to do anything else to make sure that only the record with the corresponding `_id` is removed?  If the entry is invalid why is it removing *all* records?

Comment: There's something else going on here, because your `Resource.remove` call will only return the one doc with the matching `_id`.

Comment: Please search in your code to see whether you have something like resource.remove(), which removes all records.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Resource.findOneAndRemove` [Reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove)

I've never used that but this is what I use and it works perfectly for me

```
PostModel.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    if (result) {
        PostModel.remove({_id: id}, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            res.json(200, result);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Anyway, using the way the OP provided should work [per the mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) - or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, it should but for certainty I find it first and then delete it

Comment: `findOneAndRemove` works properly, however I'm concerned about why `.remove` doesn't work.  Using the `.findOne` and then `.remove` in the callback *still* removes all of the records (as you might expect).  Looking at the entries in mongo shell I see `"_id" : ObjectId("520254601f6fe61336000003")` -- can I not use the id as a string?

Comment: That's strange; using `_id` as a string, in the mongo shell, you can't remove a doc, and mongoose says `.remove()` calls mongodb driver directly.

Comment: Ha! After `.findOne` could you do a `console.log` to see if it is only really one. @ExplosionPills

Comment: @dcodesmith there is only one, but note that the use of `.remove` in your example (and the way I am using it) does not use any data returned from `.findOne` or otherwise.  `.find` also returns only one record.

Comment: Something interesting though! I'm using `del` like this `app.del('/api/post/delete/:id', post.delete);` and not `post`